# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?

Tags: python, object, integer, typeerror

I did my research but I can not figure out why I am getting this error. Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np   

def F(t):        
    c = 3 * (10**-7)     
    P = 1     
    F_0 = np.sqrt (4 * np.pi * P / c)        
    A = F_0 * np.exp(-(t**2))(1-2(t**2))        
    return (A)        
print(F(2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `np.exp(-(t**2))(1-2(t**2))`, what is that supposed to mean? Specifically, are you expecting `np.exp(-(t**2))` to be multiplied with `(1-2(t**2))`? It does not work like that. Neither will the `(1-2(t**2))` part mean that `2` is multiplied with `t**2`. You already know how to ask for a multiplication - it is in your code several times already.

Comment: I think this should be `A = F_0 * np.exp(-(t**2*1-2*(t**2)))  `

Comment: `2(t**2)` - here you are trying to call "2" (int) with parameter `t**2`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot multiply like that in `Python`. It's not math and PEMDAS!

Use:

```
import numpy as np   

def F(t):        
    c = 3 * (10**-7)     
    P = 1     
    F_0 = np.sqrt (4 * np.pi * P / c)        
    A = F_0 * np.exp(-(t**2))*(1-2*(t**2))        
    return (A)        
print(F(2))
```